# Why overflow-y may affect horizontal layout in flex?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following flex layout:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
.main-content {
  background: blue;
  height: 130%;
}
.right {
  height: 100%;
}
.side-content-upper {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 50%;
}
.side-content-lower {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 60%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="main-content">some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-upper">more</div>
    <div class="side-content-lower">more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since heights of `.main-content` and of `.side-content-upper` plus that of `.side-content-lower` are greater than 100%, we get vertical overflow. Now let's make the first column fit the screen height and scroll separately by adding `box-sizing: border-box; overflow-y: scroll;` (to make this more compact, I align unchanged CSS into single lines):

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.container { background: red; color: white; height: 100vh; display: flex; }
.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.main-content { background: blue; height: 130%; }
.right {
  height: 100%;
}
.side-content-upper { padding: 1em; height: 50%; }
.side-content-lower { padding: 1em; height: 60%; background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="main-content">some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-upper">more</div>
    <div class="side-content-lower">more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works fine, doesn't it? Let's now apply the same style to the `.right` container:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.container { background: red; color: white; height: 100vh; display: flex; }
.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.main-content { background: blue; height: 130%; }
.right {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.side-content-upper { padding: 1em; height: 50%; }
.side-content-lower { padding: 1em; height: 60%; background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="main-content">some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-upper">more</div>
    <div class="side-content-lower">more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your screen resolution is not too high, you'll see what I'm not expecting: the right column not only fits height and gets vertical scroll, but also shrinks and gets horizontal scroll. Why is that? It doesn't seem just the width of the vertical scrollbar: switch `overflow-y` of `.right` from `scroll` to `hidden` and you again will get `.right` deformed. I'm puzzled how to reason about this. Just in case, here's what I see with `hidden`:

[image: right padding is cut off like there's limitation of width]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two 'fixes' for what it's worth - I know you're looking for an explanation more than a solution but hopefully this will help explain by example. I'm not confident I can detail the intricacies of what is happening here but it is basically do with the way scroll bars interact with with the box model, and how flex handles dimensions. If anyone more knowledgeable can shed some light please chime in.

Give the `right` div it's own `flex` property:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.container { background: red; color: white; height: 100vh; display: flex; }
.left {
  flex: 5;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.main-content { background: blue; height: 130%; }
.right {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.side-content-upper { padding: 1em; height: 50%; }
.side-content-lower { padding: 1em; height: 60%; background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="main-content">some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-upper">more</div>
    <div class="side-content-lower">more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Give the `.side-content-upper` and `.side-content-lower` a `box-sizing: border-box` property.

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.container { 
  background: red; 
  color: white; 
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
height: 100%;
padding: 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.main-content { background: blue; height: 130%; }
.right {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.side-content-upper { padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box; height: 50%; width: 100%;       }
.side-content-lower { padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box; height: 60%; background: black; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="main-content">some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-upper">more</div>
    <div class="side-content-lower">more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One final note: when you give overflow to both the `left` and `right` divs, the `container` loses its implicit `overflow: auto` which was spacing your elements for you. This was causing the shrink issue - if you add `overflow-y: scroll` back on the container in your last demo the elements will regain their original proportions.

Answer (score 0):

can use java script to help you by available screen height
 add jquery.js in first

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var y = screen.availHeight;
  $(".container").css('height',y +'px');
  $(".left").css('height',y +'px');
  $(".right").css('height',y +'px');
  $(".main-content").css('height',(y * 1.3) +'px');
  $(".side-content-upper").css('height',(y * .5) 
  +'px');
  $(".side-content-lower").css('height',(y * .6) 
  +'px');
 });
</script>   
<style type="text/css">
 body { margin: 0; }
 .container{ 
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 }
 .left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y:scroll;
 }
 .main-content{ background: blue;}
 .right{box-sizing: border-box;overflow-y: scroll;}
 .side-content-upper { padding: 1em;  }
 .side-content-lower { padding: 1em;  background: 
  black; }
</style>
```